# How to make a mask anti-aliased?

Tags: node-editor, masking

I created 2 masks in Blender's mask editor. In 1 frame of my video I created the initial mask points by using Ctrl-Click. In the other frames, I dragged them to the correct position. In the node editor, I used the "Feather" option for both of them (but I don't see any difference with or without it).

Afterwards, I noticed that one mask is anti-aliased, while the other isn't:

[image]     [image]

How can I make both masks anti-aliased?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer to the question myself.
I had drawn the first mask in a counter-clockwise direction, and the second one in a clockwise direction. That caused the second one to look different (feathering at the inside instead of the outside).
The solution was to right-click the mask and choose "Switch Direction".